# ubuntu- ADT loading screen won't show after installation

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I've installed the ADT bundle for linux-ubuntu (I've also installed the jdk and jre required).

All the installation process was according to this page- 
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux

I did every step and all seemed to go well.

Eclipse seems to run fine but the loading (splash) screen shows the Eclipse logo and not the ADT logo as expected.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: my version is 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried installing package ia32-libs?

Comment: no, but to everyone else it seems to work fine without it :(

Comment: does everyone else have the exact same Ubuntu version and/or 64 bit system?